# NextJS router using nested pages not setting active menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using NextJS and i am trying to set active menu items using the router. All 'top level' pages works fine, but if there is a page under the top level page, it does not set the active page.

```
router.pathname == "/profile" ? "active" : "not active"
```

The code above sets active for `/profile` but if for instance i have a page that is `/profile/23543456`, then it sets to not active

Is there a way to sort this out so that any sub pages of the profile also set active?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pathname field contains full route path. So in your case, `router.pathname` is `/profile/23543456`. You can check if the pathname starts with `/profile/` instead.

```
router.pathname.startsWith('/profile/') ? "active" : "not active"
```

Comment: Note that this is only really useful for 2 route segments - it isn't helpful for further nesting especially with dynamic routes e.g. `/profile/23543456/things`